# After global install of gulp, command not found

Tags: macos, bash, path, npm, gulp

After an apparently successful global install of gulp, I still get "command not found" for gulp commands such as `gulp -v`.  I tried adding a couple of things to $PATH (specifics below) but it didn't help. I suspect I need to determine where the global install of gulp is so I can add that to $PATH. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

OSX 10.9.5

My input into the terminal is in bold below, in gray boxes is terminal output in response

**npm install -g gulp**

```
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
/Users/mh/.node/bin/gulp -> /Users/mh/.node/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
/Users/mh/.node/lib
└── gulp@3.9.1
```

**gulp -v**

```
-bash: gulp: command not found
```

I tried adding the three paths displayed at the end of the gulp install to `/etc/paths` (see last three lines below). The three paths do show up when I `echo $PATH` but `gulp -v` still fails.

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/Users/mh/.node/lib
/Users/mh/.node/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/
/Users/mh/.node/bin/gulp
```

**gulp** **-v**

```
-bash: gulp: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you installed gulp a symlink from `/Users/mh/.node/bin/gulp` to `/Users/mh/.node/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js` was created.

However you shouldn't add that symlink itself to your `$PATH`. You have to add the directory it is in:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/mh/.node/bin"
```

That should do the trick.